# Restsharp not returning any data Get request and Post Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I am learning how to use RestSharp to make my web api calls. When l make a get request with Postman it returns 200 and in the body it gives me null instead of json  and when l make a post request with Postman it returns a 204(no content).
All suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Here is my product class with the set and get mehtods:

```
        public class Product
         {
          public string ProductName { get; set; }
          public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
          public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
          public string Shop { get; set; }
           }
```

Here is my products controller class:

```
      public class ProductsController : ApiController
       {
          Product[] p = new Product[]
           {
           new  Product { ProductName = "JIM", Manufacturer = "Kofi",  ProductPrice = "22", Shop = "12"}
           };



    // GET: api/Products
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:4282/");
        var request = new RestRequest("api/products", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        var response = client.Execute<List<Product>>(request);
        return response.Data;

        }

    // POST: api/Products
    public void Post([FromBody] Product p)
      {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:4282/");
        var request = new RestRequest("api/products", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddJsonBody(p);
        client.Execute(request);
          }
```

.

Comment: You don't actually seem to return anything in `GetAll`

Comment: @ediblecode l updated the question to return response.Data

Comment: I'm still confused. Your `GetAll` method seems to just call itself? The comment says `api/products/5` but its getting all of them then surely the URL is `api/products`

Comment: @ediblecode yes its a comment, the url is api/products, you can ignore the 5

Comment: So you call `api/products` and then inside the code for that method, you call `api/products`. It looks like its just repeatedly calling itself?